# Angular 10 CORE blocks my rest call to local ms

Tags: angular

I'm trying to call in my local Angular (10) project to a rest call that my Java project exposes.

I'm getting the following error :

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/my-cool-ms/v1/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I saw previous posts about this topic but the solutions suggested didn't help.

My implementation :

```
  private sendGetRequestWithParams(param1: string, param2: string, url: string): Observable<any> {
    const options = {
      params: new HttpParams()
        .set('param1', param1)
        .set('param2', param2),
      headers: new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')
        .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        .set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS'),
    };

    return this.http.get<object[]>(url, options)
      .pipe(
        tap(data => console.log('received :' + JSON.stringify(data))),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
```

I saw also [another solution](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md) using proxy but it shouldn't be used in production so why my other option for production ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISSUE:

Angular CLI provides a development server that runs on localhost:4200 by default. Your backend server is running on localhost:8080 this means you may have CORS issues if your server is not configured properly.

Note: even if your backend is running on localhost, it will be listenning on a different port, which is treated as a different domain.

FIX:

Like you said, using a proxy will fix this. Angular CLI has a good build-in option to do this.
For production the solution will depend on how you configure your production environment. For basic applications your backend and frontend will be hosted on the same domain, so CORS will not be an issue here.

This is how your proxy.conf.json would look like:

```
    {
      "/my-cool-ms": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8080",
        "secure": false
        "pathRewrite": {
           "^/api": ""
        }
      }
    }
```

edit: Because your backend url has the port 8080 used I am assuming your backend is using JAVA. Continuing on this assumption: to get your application in production you will need to compile your frontend and move it into the target folder before compiling your backend to a war/jar.

Another solution would be to configure your server to allow CORS requests OR deploy a proxy server in production.

Comment: in the proxy solution, do I need to configure a mapping for every endpoint ? For example if my localhost has multiple endpoints (localhost:8000/logic1/  localhost:8000/logic2/ ...) do I need to configure mapping only the localhost:8000 or for each endpoint?

Comment: @JeyJ No, you don't have to configure each endpoint, just the first part (root). I updated the answer to include the config.

Comment: I did exactly that, but not sure why it redirects all the endpoints to the localhost:8080. I'm seeing the following msg in the local console : [HPM] GET /api/logic1/v1/ -> http://localhost:8080 and in the browsers console I see the following error : http://localhost:4200/api/logic1/v1/ 404 (Not Found) .  It looks like it redirects the entire endpoint to localhost:8080

Comment: I had to add also :     "pathRewrite": {"^/api" : ""} . Can you add it to your answer please ? I'll mark it as the post`s answer afterwards